# Is it possible to bubblesorting an array of objects?

Tags: java, arrays, object, bubble-sort

I have an array of objects populated by a .txt file

```
Object[] punteggiTutti = scores.toArray();
```

Even if it's possible to use the .sort function:

```
Arrays.sort(punteggiTutti, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

I would know how to apply a working bubblesort algorithm; I tried the following not working code:

```
for(int i=0; i<j; i++) 
    {
    if(punteggiTutti[i]<punteggiTutti[i+1])  // error "<" operator cannot be used in objects 
      {
      temp=punteggiTutti[i]; 
      punteggiTutti[i]=punteggiTutti[i+1];
      punteggiTutti[i+1]=temp;
      }
    }
```

Comment: < cannot be used in java.lang.Object

Comment: Do you understand what the error means?

Comment: Of course I do!!!
So the answer to my question is simply... not possible?! :)

Comment: it's an array created from a .txt file
In the first file i have team scores
In the second file i have the name of teams. 
I need bubble sort to create a unique index which can sort both of the arrays created from the 2 files
Any ideas?

Comment: You need to figure out how to compare your objects.

Comment: file1: {Seattle, Chicago, Houston}
file2: {22,44,33}

output should be
Chicago 44
Houston 33
Seattle 22     

i want to sort file2, creating an index which can sort also file1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't compare two Objects with < operator.

Use something which implements Comparable interface. Then such elements can be compared using function a.compareTo(b);

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Also have a look at:
http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html

Try to read about equality in Java. This should help you with future errors when using Java.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Comparator for your object, to compare on object against the other.
The built in mergeSort algorithm is much faster than bubblesort.

http://www.iti.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/sortieren/sortcontest/sortcontest.htm
http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/